# Photoshop script - How to toggles between 2 linked layer groups

Tags: java, scripting, layer, bounds, photoshop-script

I am a Photoshop beginner and currently use version Photoshop CC2015.

However, one command I feel Photoshop must have is to create function to toggles between 2 linked layers

I have to switch manually which I feel can be automated using scripting which are difficult for me being a beginner.

Can anybody help me in this regard.

Thanks very much! Let me donate a little bit of money to anyone who can do it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sngnd.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3K54.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cvTW.jpg)

Comment: [Adobe Photoshop Scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to switch between two layers, it's super easy:

```
var layer = activeDocument.activeLayer;
var linkedLayers = layer.linkedLayers;
if (linkedLayers.length > 0) {
  activeDocument.activeLayer = linkedLayers[0];
}
```

[image]

cycling through 2+ however would require a different approach.

Comment: You are so talented. I bought your Toggletator to support you!

Comment: The dialog box opens automatically every time I toggle! Is there any way for not to show inner layers?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEvxc.gif

Comment: @Cao you mean that groups expand? I don't think so, unfortunately, there are no options to disable groups from expanding

Comment: If layer groups expand, you can collapse it via script. If this is the issue plesee let me know may be I can help u.

Comment: Hello Charu! I have some trouble when switching? Can you help me?